# error en recorrer bucles

Tags: php, html, array

quiero desplegar un menú mediante una conexión de base de datos.
pero solo me despliega un sub menú en cada menú. cree una conexion a la base de datos mi función que retorna la respuesta se llama sqll

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
<?php include "Conexion.php"; 
$prueba=new Conexion("root","","cpb","127.0.0.1");
$titulos=$prueba->sqll("SELECT pa.id me,pa.nombre mprincipal FROM parent                 
pa,papel p where p.id=pa.id_papel");
foreach ($titulos as $key){?>
<li class="sub-menu">
<a href="#">
<i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
<span><?php echo $key["mprincipal"];?></span>
</a>
<?php 
$menu=$prueba->sqll("SELECT * FROM menu where id_parent=".$key["me"]);
foreach ($menu as $sub){?>
<ul class="sub">
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $sub["link"]; ?>"><?php echo $sub["label"];?>                
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<?php }} ?>
</ul>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Vaya pregunta... No se si a mi me corresponde dar bienvenida y todo eso

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow, daniel! A tu pregunta le hace falta muchísima información para poder ayudarte... Por favor, haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para darte una idea cómo hacer una pregunta que sea bien recibida en la comunidad.

Comment: Con la poca información que dejas en tu pregunta me pareciera que el error es que no lo estas obteniendo de forma asociativa, sin embargo necesitaria ver el error para determinar que sea eso e igual que comentes que quieres lograr

Comment: gracias por tomarse el tiempo en leer la pregunta agradezco su colaboración corregi la pregunta pero encontré el error, estaba en la etiqueta <li>  tenia que terminar en el segundo foreach

Comment: Dudo que lo hayas arreglado correctamente, porque dentro del segundo ciclo creas una lista para cada elemento. Semánticamente, no es correcto.

Comment: gracias por el comentario me podrias explicar la manera correcta